# problem with: conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I have made table called "ComeGo" in SQL Server By MS Visual Studio and it has 12 columns

## and there code:

```
(
    [CGID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [CGDate] DATETIME2 NULL, 
    [CGTime] DATETIME2 NULL, 
    [CGUserName] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
    [CGComeDate] DATETIME2 NULL, 
    [CGComeTime] DATETIME2 NULL, 
    [CGComeNotes] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
    [CGGODate] DATETIME2 NULL, 
    [CGGOTime] DATETIME2 NULL, 
    [CGGONotes] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
    [CGDefference] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
    [ActionBy] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL 
)
```

## Now when I debug that code:

```
    Dim ComeGoCheck As String
    ComeGoCheck = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ComeGo WHERE CGUserName=@CGUserName AND CGGoDate=@CGGoDate"
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(ComeGoCheck, Con)
    Dim query As Integer
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CGUserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = GoForm_CGUserName_TextBox.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CGGoDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = GoForm_CGGoDate_DateTimePicker.Value
    Con.Open()
    query = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    Con.Close()
    If query > 0 Then
        MsgBox("لقد تم تسجيل انصراف الموظف مسبقا")
        Con.Close()
    Else
        GoForm_DataGridView(7, GoForm_DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value = Now.Date
        GoForm_DataGridView(8, GoForm_DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value = Now
        'Count TimeDiff Between DateCome And DateGo
        GoForm_DataGridView(10, GoForm_DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value = DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, GoForm_DataGridView(5, GoForm_DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value, GoForm_DataGridView(8, GoForm_DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value) / 60
        ComeGoCMD = New SqlCommand(" Update ComeGo SET 
                    CGDefference = " & GoForm_DataGridView(10, GoForm_DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value & ",
                    CGGODate = '" & GoForm_DataGridView(7, GoForm_DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value & "',
                    CGGOTime = '" & GoForm_DataGridView(8, GoForm_DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value & "',
                    CGGONotes = '" & GoForm_DataGridView(9, GoForm_DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value & "' 
                    where 
                    CGID = " & GoForm_DataGridView(0, GoForm_DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index).Value & "", Con)
        Con.Open()
        ComeGoCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Con.Close()
        'Show Message Box
        MsgBox("User Go Registred")
        'Reload ComeGo Table With New UpDates
        Load_ComeGo()
        Con.Close()
    End If
```

## I got error at:

```
ComeGoCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

## and it saying:

> conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: I think you need to convert this parameter input to date format: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@CGGoDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Parse(GoForm_CGGoDate_DateTimePicker.Value)`.

Comment: This has to be date: `GoForm_CGGoDate_DateTimePicker.Value` or parse it like this: `DateTime.Parse(GoForm_CGGoDate_DateTimePicker.Value)`

Comment: You need to change your update statement to use parameters instead of concatenating strings. Not only will it solve your current issue, it will also protect you from SQL Injection attacks. Also, please don't use irrelevant tags. Your database is SQL Server and your code is VB.Net, Why did you tag c# and MySql?

Comment: the same evenn it show error to replace `DateTime` To `Date` only

Comment: As @ZoharPeled suggested, you should be using parameters with your `UPDATE` statement just as you are with your `SELECT`. For one thing, it doesn't make sense to do the same thing two different ways. **ALWAYS** use parameters to insert variable values into SQL code.

Comment: @ZoharPeled i fixed tags sorry am noob here ^-^ .. am searching about what u mentioned that `parameters` and thanks for ur notes :)

Comment: Actually You've made a mess of the tags. The most relevant tags would be vb.Net and sql-server. vba and visual-studio are irrelevant.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for ur comment <3 .. but am noob here and still learning , can u please make example on my code to learn from it ??

Comment: @ZoharPeled sorry about that :(

Comment: @ZoharPeled can u please make example on my code to learn from it about that `parameters` coz am noob here and am still learning ??

Comment: You are already working with parameters in your select statement. Just use it as an example for the update statement.

Comment: as like that ??
`Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(ComeGoCheck, Con)`
`cmd2 = New SqlCommand("UPDATE ComeGo SET CGGODate = @CGGODate, CGGOTime = @CGGOTime, CGGONotes = @CGGONotes, where CGID = CGID", Con)`

`cmd.Parameters.Add("@CGGODate", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = Now.Date`
 
`cmd.Parameters.Add("@CGGOTime", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = Now`

`cmd.Parameters.Add("@CGGONotes", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = GoForm_CGGoNotes_TextBox.Text`

Comment: Yes, something like that

Comment: still the same and am still trying........... can u help me with the code ??

Comment: Change the datatype of your `CGGODate` to `Date`

Comment: @kiLLua tried and the same :(

Comment: You declared `Dim cmd2` but you put the parameters in `cmd` please be consistent on your variable declarations. maybe this is where you got your error.
found it out on your comment.

Comment: @kiLLua i have made it `cmd2` and fixed the parameters declarations ,, and the same ............... :(